# Windows 7 Slipstream will not enter Audit Mode

Tags: windows-7

I have two sets of Dell Laptops that I'm trying to install Windows 7 x64 on. I downloaded the driver packs from Dell's Enterprise site, and slipstreamed them into my `install.wim` file. On one notebook, it works perfectly fine, and I can enter Audit mode. On the other, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, and am presented with a black screen with the mouse cursor. Nothing happens, I can't bring up any tools (i.e. Task Manager, UtilMan, etc). All I can do is restart.

I tried to kill the OOBE on the reboot, but then I was left without an account to use to log in. If I use the UtilMan-CMD hack, I can use the Administrator profile, but `sysprep.exe` will not load - It claims Windows Updates are requiring a reboot, and to try again. Even after rebooting, no change.

How can I get into Audit Mode on this second model? I have tried waiting over an hour to see if it will do its automatic reboot to enter Audit mode, but it never does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core issue unknown, but it's solved.

After attempting to log in to Audit mode, I tried rebooting into Safe Mode. It brought up the message that you can't complete setup in Safe Mode, then it restarted *in Audit Mode* automatically after rebooting.

If anyone knows *why* this would happen, please feel free to edit.